# Need help to select multiple variable from dplyr::Groupby

Tags: r

Extract the daily COVID-19 confirmed cases for City1, City2, and City3 from all the cities. Normalize the daily COVID-19 confirmed cases for the three cities using their respective populations. The 2019 mid-year estimated population figures for City1, City2, and City3 are 100,000, 200,000, and 300,000 respectively.

```
'''
df <- read.csv ("coronavirus.csv", header = TRUE )
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(City.name) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Daily.cases))
'''
```

Cant select multiple variables from dplyr::Groupby. Can anyone help me with the right code along with the second part of the question as I am not able to find solution as well.

Comment: For example: There are 3 columns. 1. "City Name", 2. "Area", 3. "Population". There are 20 cities in column 1. 50 areas in column 2. How can I receive a summation of specific 3 cities using dplyr::Groupby?

Comment: Try `df %>% filter(City.name %in% c("City1", "City2", "City3")) %>% group_by(City.name) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Daily.cases, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: Thank you very much akrun. I find the solution of the first question....You are halpful..